# Extracting Atom from webpages/blogs

Tags: java, atom-feed

I am trying to parse atom feeds from a webpage. But the third line shows error and when I tried to fix this "it shows an option :"configure build path". How can I fix it?I tried to fix it but it's not get fixed.Please help me to fix this

```
URL feedUrl = new URL("http://localhost:8080/namespace/feed/");
SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(feedUrl));
System.out.println("Feed Title: " + feed.getTitle());
```

This is the code Which I had tried

```
try {
URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=robbery&tbm=blg&
output=atom");SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(url));
System.out.println("Feed Title: " + feed.getTitle());
for (SyndEntry entry : (List<SyndEntry>) feed.getEntries())
{
System.out.println("Title: " + entry.getTitle());
System.out.println("Unique Identifier: " + entry.getUri());
System.out.println("Updated Date: " + entry.getUpdatedDate());
for (SyndLinkImpl link : (List<SyndLinkImpl>) entry.getLinks())
{
System.out.println("Link: " + link.getHref());}           
for (SyndContentImpl content : (List<SyndContentImpl>) entry.getContents())
{
System.out.println("Content: " + content.getValue());
}


for (SyndCategoryImpl category : (List<SyndCategoryImpl>) entry.getCategories())
{
System.out.println("Category: " + category.getName());
}
}//for
}//try
catch (Exception ex) 
{
}
```

}

Comment: I suppose you are using rome, be sure you have all rome dependencies in your classpath adding the required libraries to build path.

Comment: I included all jdom and rome libraries.But I don't know where I went wrong?

Comment: What rome version are you using?

Comment: currently using rome-1.0

Comment: It works for me, check your build path again, clean your project and try again.

Comment: still not working..can you tell me the links of the required jar files to check whether I included the same thing

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/rome/rome/1.0 and http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jdom/jdom/1.0, I recommend using maven to manage your project.

Comment: @vzamanillo now the error is fixed.But it does not show any output.Is same thing happened when you checked that?

Comment: Please, run your code in debug mode, you will get a 403 code.

Comment: @vzamanillo yes if I catch that exception I get the same 403 code. But I don't know what is the problem with my code.Why it doesn't shows any output. Can you fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are using [Rome](http://rometools.github.io/rome/), be sure you have all Rome dependencies in your classpath adding the required libraries to build path.

Your code works for me so, maybe your libraries are corrupt, you can donwload it again from

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/rome/rome/1.0

and

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jdom/jdom/1.0

(I recommend use [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) to manage your project.)

then add the libraries to your build path again, clean your project and run it again.

You are getting a HTTP 403 error code because Google blocks the unrecognized HTTP clients, your HTTP client needs to be a recognized client like Chrome, MSIE, Gecko... etc, set the [User Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) to your HTTP client and will work.

Try this code:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.List;

import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndCategoryImpl;
import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndContentImpl;
import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndEntry;
import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed;
import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndLinkImpl;
import com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedInput;
import com.sun.syndication.io.XmlReader;

public class Rome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URLConnection urlConnection = new URL("https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=robbery&tbm=blg&output=atom").openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows NT; DigExt)");

            SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
            input.setPreserveWireFeed(true);
            SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(urlConnection));
            System.out.println("Feed Title: " + feed.getTitle());
            for (SyndEntry entry : (List<SyndEntry>) feed.getEntries()) {
                System.out.println("Title: " + entry.getTitle());
                System.out.println("Unique Identifier: " + entry.getUri());
                System.out.println("Updated Date: " + entry.getUpdatedDate());
                for (SyndLinkImpl link : (List<SyndLinkImpl>) entry.getLinks()) {
                    System.out.println("Link: " + link.getHref());
                }
                for (SyndContentImpl content : (List<SyndContentImpl>) entry.getContents()) {
                    System.out.println("Content: " + content.getValue());
                }

                for (SyndCategoryImpl category : (List<SyndCategoryImpl>) entry.getCategories()) {
                    System.out.println("Category: " + category.getName());
                }
            }// for
        }// try
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }

    }
}
```